# What does IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2 mean in Android-Universal-Image-Loader?

Tags: android

I'm reading the source of *[Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/UniversalImageLoader/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/assist/ImageScaleType.java)*.

I can't understand what ImageScaleType.**IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2** means.

It says:**"It's fast type and it's preferable for usage in lists/grids/galleries (and other AdapterView)"**.

Why it's fast and why it's preferable for usage in adapterViews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too sure about this, but I would assume that this enum value describes how many pixels ('samples') are taken, probably to calculate a single pixel of the output image.

The calculation would then typically take the average value of a number of source samples, like `newValue = (srcValue[1] + srcValue[2] + ... srcValue[n]) / n`. And the division by `n` can be computed very fast if and when `n` is a power of 2 by bit-shifting integer values. If `n` is not a power of two a 'real' division operation is needed, which is computationally much more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](http://javadox.com/com.nostra13.universalimageloader/universal-image-loader/1.9.0/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/assist/ImageScaleType.html):

**IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2**

Image will be reduces 2-fold until next reduce step make image smaller target size.

Comment: After reading that doc, I think that my answer was not correct. Apparently, `POWER_OF_2` is a misnomer and should actually be `MULTIPLE_OF_2` or just `EVEN` because the image is reduced to 1/2 (effectively 1/4 I guess) its size before further transformations and that speeds up the following operations.

Answer (score 0):

It is a scale factor that is applied to the image. If it is set to `2` then the image will have its width and height cut in half. Which means it will use less memory, but also occupy a smaller "box" on the screen.